# How to redirect and authorize the same url which return the jsp page in ajax success

Tags: java, ajax, spring-security

I have a spring boot controller method that returns a JSP page. I have spring security implementation to authorize every request. This is my controller which returns to the home page on clicking the icon.

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String getDataForHome(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
{
   return "/dashboard";
}
```

Now the icon which returns to the home page is-

```
<img src="<%=contextPath%>/assets/img/logo.png" onclick="handleClick();">
```

The implementation of handleClick function from where the ajax call to the controller with authorization and redirect to the home page in ajax success is-

```
function handleClick(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "<%=contextPath%>/home",
            headers: {
                'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
            },              
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
               window.location='<%= contextPath %>/home';
            }
            error:function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
         });
 }
```

**Now clicking on the image shows full authentication is required for the request.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured [view resolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s05.html) use `return "dashboard"` (without /)

if you are trying to forward the request to another controller handle within the request, use `return "forward:/dashboard"`.

If you want to redirect to a new request use `return "redirect:/dashboard"`